# Error when updating DB: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using EF6 and have been making a few changes to my model.
Now all the sudden I get the following error when trying to update my database through the nuget command *Update-Database*:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

I did not change anything in my connection settings (or *web.config* in general) but here's my connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\LM.DataAccess.mdf;Initial Catalog=LM.DataAccess;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

In **Server Explorer** -> **Data Connections** I can access the database without any problems.

What could be the issue here? I tried deleting the database through the **SQL Server Object Explorer** but I still get the error.

Still need help people.
Would really appreciate if someone could help me out - I've tried everything I could!

Answer (score 9):

Thats caused when your migrations project is not the StartUp project, which means you'll need to set the connectionstring in the StartUp project for it to work correctly.

Hope it helps.
Best Regards.

Comment: Thanks!  This fixed my problem.  I didn't realize that needed to be set in order for the command to find the web.config and the right connection.  I thought the "Default project" option in the package manager console would be enough.  What on earth is the default project for then, anyway?

Comment: @DanCsharpster the "Default project" is the project where the PMC will execute your command in. I think the reason why connectionstring must be in the startUp project .config file is because thats the .config file used by IIS to emulate the server on your machine, i mean, i guess IIS ignores the others .config files and uses the startUP ones. Maybe the commands is doing the same. I'll check this later! Glad it helped!!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, In my case the connection string is being read from the web project not the EntityFramework project, so i made the my Web project the Solution StartUp project so the Package Console Manager can read the connection string, and in Package Console Manager i choosed EntityFramework project as Default project.

Answer (score 2):

Follow step by step:
1./ Create right connect to database in web.config
1./ Right click -> select "Set as default project"
2./ run update-database againt

That's fix.

Answer (score 0):

An error like this can happen if you have multiple projects in the solution. Run update-database - Verbose and ensure that the default project in the package manager console and the StartUp project in the solution explorer are set to the project which contains the code migrations.