# Why won't connection string work for EF migration?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, database-connection

I have created a database for use with a NuGet Gallery implementation.  I can see the database in sql manager 2012 and I can access it from a test program I wrote, using my connection string.  However, when I try to run the Update-Database command in the package manager console, to have EF set up the database, I keep getting the error: "The server was not found or was not accessible.".

Here's more detail:

```
PM> Update-Database -Verbose

Using StartUp project 'NuGetGallery.Operations'. 
Using NuGet project 'NuGetGallery'. 
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database. 

System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: 
An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. 
This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string.
Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct. ---> 

System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. ---> 

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26

- Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
```

Here's my connection string in the NuGet Gallery MVC site:

```
    <add name="Gallery.SqlServer" connectionString="Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Database=NuGetGallery11;User ID=testuser;Password=notmyrealpassword;Connect Timeout=60" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

And here's my test program.  The connection strings are identical in both applications.

```
            var sqlConnection2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Gallery.SqlServer"].ConnectionString);
        sqlConnection2.Open();
        using (sqlConnection2) {
            var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Foo", sqlConnection2);

            var foo = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (foo.Read()) {
                int id = foo.GetInt32(0);
                var name = foo.GetString(1);
                var email = foo.GetString(2);

                Console.WriteLine("ID:{0}, Name:{1}, Email:{2}", id, name, email);

            }
        }
        Console.Read();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: you need to google on how to format a connection string when connecting to a Database via EF here is a link you can look at to find a working example [C# connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

Comment: Where's the class that is meant to derive from DbContext?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem was solved in this other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29665326/1073742).  You have to set the default project in the manager console AND set the startup project for the solution in order for the update command to find the connection string and also what Aydin said, but in this case that part was already set up for me.

Comment: "AND set the startup project for the solution in order for the update command to find the connection string"

This fixed my problem. Thank You. Thank You. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that EntityFramework doesn't know that your connection string is named `Gallery.SqlServer`...

Here's how you can setup entity framework from scratch...

1. Open VS with Administrative rights *(just being cautious)*
2. Create a new `Console application`
3. Open the package manager console

   - Type in: `PM> Install-Package EntityFramework
4. Open the `App.Config` file

   - Add the following

     ```
     <connectionStrings>
       <add name="Gallery.SqlServer" connectionString="Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Database=GalleryExample;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
     </connectionStrings>
     ```
5. Create a new class called `Foo`

   ```
   public class Foo
   {
       public Foo()
       {
           this.Id = Guid.NewGuid()
                         .ToString();
       }

       public string Id { get; set; }
   }
   ```
6. Create a new class called `EfContext`

   ```
   public class EfContext : DbContext
   {
       public EfContext()
           : base("Gallery.SqlServer")
       {

       }
       public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
   }
   ```
7. Open up the package manager console again

   - PM> Enable-Migrations
   - PM> Add-Migration InitialMigration
   - PM> Update-Database
8. Enjoy your new db....

Comment: Aydin, thanks for your help.  That worked for creating a simple example but I'm still confused as to why mine doesn't work.  To be clear, this is the source for the NuGet Gallery from its github repo, which should be fully working.  It already has a constructor that takes the connection name as a param for migrations:

public EntitiesContext()
            : base("Gallery.SqlServer") // Use the connection string in a web.config (if one is found)
        {
        }

Comment: You credentials may actually be the culprit... as far as I'm aware, LocalDB uses Windows auth, and if my example worked yet the other didn't, then it must be your connection string, and the only difference between my connection string and yours is that yours attempts to hand over a username and pass

Comment: I figured it out!  It looks like in addition to setting the Default project to NuGetGallery in the package manager console, you also have to set NuGetGallery as the startup project for the solution in order for it to read from the right web.config file.  That seems a bit annoying and redundant to have to specify that project twice in order to find the web.config and connection string, but I guess that's Microsoft for you.

Comment: hahahahaha, I'm surprised I overlooked that as I generally keep entity framework and domain models in a separate library from the startup project and target them explicitly when applying migrations through npm