# Method keeping me from using updated values and tables not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio

Weird bug I am running into. I am seeding data using the SchoolInitializer but I am getting data pushed into the Student table and not the Employee and Course table. I've added a new Student into the list students but my table was not updating and my view was not displaying the new student. HOWEVER, I removed the protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) method and my tables updated with the new Student, the courses, and the enrollment data and the view displayed the appropriate information. Is there something this method is doing that I know nothing about or is it some kind of coincidence? I am constantly closing the connection to the database, cleaning rebuilding, and running without debugging.

```
namespace MyFirstWebApplication.Models
{
    public class SchoolInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SchoolContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(SchoolContext context)
        {
            var students = new List<Student>
            {
                new Student{FirstName = "James", LastName= "Dean", EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2014-01-02") },
                new Student{FirstName = "Lynda", LastName = "Thames", EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-11-02")}
            };

            foreach (var temp in students)
            {
                context.Students.Add(temp);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();

            var courses = new List<Course>
            {
                new Course{CourseName = "Java", TotalCredits = 4},
                new Course{CourseName = "C#", TotalCredits = 4}
            };

            foreach (var temp in courses)
            {
                context.Courses.Add(temp);
            }

            //context.SaveChanges();

            var enrollments = new List<Enrollment>
            {
                new Enrollment{StudentId = 1, CourseId = 1, Grade = 3},
                new Enrollment{StudentId = 1, CourseId = 2, Grade = 4}
            };

            foreach (var temp in enrollments)
            {
                context.Enrollments.Add(temp);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
} 

namespace MyFirstWebApplication.Models
{
    public class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {   //enables CRUD functionality
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you remove onmodelbuilder? And how are your attempting to initialize this?  Via Nuget Package Manager?

Comment: I removed OnModelCreating because it was unknown code to me. I know that it removes some default convention but I wasn't sure if it had some properties unknown to me, since it is being overriden

Comment: Nevermind. Even though it is commented out and I've been adding more data after the initial commenting out, the tables are still not being updated :/ So I guess it was coincidence

Comment: OnModelBuilder is important if you're using CodeFirst, also your seed values aren't being updated because you're not udating your database

Comment: Okay, so this is what is going on. I make data, I comment that method, data gets updated. I keep adding new students, no changes are happening to the view or the table. I uncomment that method, data gets updated. What the hell?

Comment: Hold on, wheres your ConnectionString

Comment: <add name="SchoolContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\School.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MyFirstWebApplication-20150430091621;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Answer (score 0):

Have your visual studio window up, make sure nothing is commented out in your SchoolContext.OnModelBuilder method...

1. With VS open, press `Ctrl` + `Q`
2. Type `Package Manager Console` then hit enter
3. On the output tab that should have appeared, type in `Update-Database`

EntityFramework should do its thing, and your values should pop up

---

You're also missing your ConnectionString which would cause you to have weird issues like the ones you've listed...

Ensure that you have this in our App.Config OR Web.Config...

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=SchoolEtc;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Next I need you to go back to you `SchoolContext` class

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {}

   //enables CRUD functionality
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

After you've completed that...

1. Type in this shortcut `CTRL + Q`... Type in `Package Manager Console`
2. Enter `Enable-Migrations`
3. Enter `Add-Migration InitialMigration`
4. Enter `Update-Database`

After that you should see the changes.

Comment: It first tells me that no migration configurations have been found in the assembly. Tells me to use the Enable Migrations. Then it tells me to enable migrations for two different Models. Should I do so?

Comment: yes... so this is what you have to do... Type in `Enable-Migrations` hit enter.. after that, type in `Add-Migration InitialMigration` hit enter... Then type in Update-Database

Comment: Sorry, but it still not working :(
I don't know what else to do

Comment: I answered a similar question to yours a while back, best thing to do is start from scratch using Entity Framework alone in a console app.. follow the instructions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905785/why-wont-connection-string-work-for-ef-migration/29906222#29906222  once you have that proof of concept working you can come back to here

Comment: Thank you. I will get back to you.